# How to create a reusable backbone/backbone.marionette component such a datagrid?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am pretty new to Backbone and Backbone.Marionette. I succeed to create a simple page with a sort of datagrid that allows me paging (first, previous, next, last pages), quick searching (triggered at each time a key is pressed), choosing the number of items shown on page (5, 10, all, ...)

Now that I have something working, I tried to improve that and to make these features as a sort of reusable component but I do not know exactly the way to follow. I do not know how to start to refine the work already done.

For example, I want to be able to change the collection/model manage by the datagrid without rewriting everything. This is where I am not confident how to do that and it is probably due to a lack of knowledge. So your inputs and advice to go further will be really appreciated and welcomed.

```
// JST and HAML Assets is used for the templating pre-compilation
Backbone.Marionette.Renderer.render = function(template, data) {
  if (!JST[template]) {
    throw "Template '" + template + "' not found!";
  }
  return JST[template](data);
};

window.MyApp = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

MyApp.addRegions({
  content: ".content-box"
});

MyApp.Datagrid = (function() {
  var Datagrid, ItemPerPageView, Layout, PagerView, QuickSearchView, Theme, ThemeView, Themes, ThemesView;

  Datagrid = {};

  Layout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    template: "layouts/grid",
    regions: {
      grid: "#grid",
      quickSearch: "#quickSearch",
      itemPerPage: "#itemPerPage",
      pager: ".pager"
    }
  });

  Theme = Backbone.Model.extend();

  Themes = Backbone.ExtendedCollection.paginatedCollection.extend({
    url: "/themes",
    model: Theme,

    initialize: function() {
      var _this = this;

      MyApp.vent.on("quickSearch:term", function(term) {
        _this.quickSearch(term);
      });

      MyApp.vent.on("itemPerPage:count", function(count) {
        _this.perPage(count);
      });

      MyApp.vent.on("pager:previous", function() {
        _this.previous();
      });

      MyApp.vent.on("pager:next", function() {
        _this.next();
      });

      MyApp.vent.on("pager:first", function() {
        _this.first();
      });

      MyApp.vent.on("pager:last", function() {
        _this.last();
      });
    }
  });

  ThemeView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: "tr",
    template: "theme",
    model: Theme,

    events: {
      "click span": "edit",
      "blur input": "save"
    },

    edit: function(event) {
      var id, span;
      id = this.model.get("id");
      span = $("span", this.el).hide();
      $("input", this.el).show().focus().val(span.text());
    },

    save: function(event) {
      var id, input, span;
      id = this.model.get("id");
      span = $("span", this.el).show();
      input = $("input", this.el).hide();
      if (this.model.get("name") !== input.val()) {
        this.model.set("name", input.val());
        this.model.save();
      }
      span.text(this.model.get("name"));
    }
  });

  ThemesView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: "index",
    model: Theme,
    itemView: ThemeView,
    collection: Themes,
    itemViewContainer: "#themes",

    serializeData: function() {
      return this.data;
    }
  });

  QuickSearchView = Backbone.Marionette.View.extend({
    el: "#quickSearch",

    events: {
      "keyup input": "search"
    },

    search: function(event) {
      var searchTerm;
      searchTerm = this.$("input").val().trim();
      MyApp.vent.trigger("quickSearch:term", searchTerm);
    }
  });

  ItemPerPageView = Backbone.Marionette.View.extend({
    el: "#itemPerPage",

    events: {
      "change select": "count"
    },

    count: function(event) {
      var count;
      count = this.$("select").val();
      MyApp.vent.trigger("itemPerPage:count", count);
    }
  });

  PagerView = Backbone.Marionette.View.extend({
    el: ".pager",

    events: {
      "click #next": "next",
      "click #previous": "previous",
      "click #first": "first",
      "click #last": "last"
    },

    first: function(event) {
      MyApp.vent.trigger("pager:first");
    },

    last: function(event) {
      MyApp.vent.trigger("pager:last");
    },

    next: function(event) {
      MyApp.vent.trigger("pager:next");
    },

    previous: function(event) {
      MyApp.vent.trigger("pager:previous");
    }
  });

  Datagrid.initializeLayout = function() {
    var collection;

    Datagrid.layout = new Layout();

    Datagrid.layout.on("show", function() {
      MyApp.vent.trigger("layout:rendered");
    });

    MyApp.content.show(Datagrid.layout);

    collection = new Themes();
    collection.fetch();

    collection.on("reset", function() {
      return Datagrid.layout.grid.show(new ThemesView({
        collection: collection
      }));
    });
  };

  MyApp.vent.on("layout:rendered", function() {
    var itemPerPageView, pagerView, quickSearchView;

    quickSearchView = new QuickSearchView();
    Datagrid.layout.quickSearch.attachView(quickSearchView);

    itemPerPageView = new ItemPerPageView();
    Datagrid.layout.itemPerPage.attachView(itemPerPageView);

    pagerView = new PagerView();
    Datagrid.layout.pager.attachView(pagerView);
  });

  return Datagrid;
})();

MyApp.addInitializer(function() {
  MyApp.Datagrid.initializeLayout();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  return MyApp.start();
});
```

**Edit 1:**

Based on the answer given and my own ideas, I wrote a first draft of a solution. I did not succeed to write a real reusable component but I have a solution that consolidate my code. Some part need to be refactored and improved. There are also some pitfals that I want to solve in a later refactoring.

To add some context, the application is written with Rails as the backend. So there is my javascript folder structure

```
assets
|--javascripts
   |--application.js
   |--admin
      |--admin.js
      |--admin.layout.js
      |--subthemes
         |--admin.subtheme.controller.js
         |--admin.subtheme.view.js
      |--themes
         |--admin.theme.controller.js
         |--admin.theme.view.js
|--templates
   |--admin
      |--subthemes
         |--index.hamlc
         |--subtheme.hamlc
      |--themes
         |--index.hamlc
         |--theme.hamlc
   |--layouts
      |--grid.hamlc
```

First, the application.js start. The assets pipelines from Rails 3.2 will prepare the dependencies as expected:

```
//= require underscore
//= require backbone
//= require backbone.marionette
//= require_tree ./lib/backbone
//= require hamlcoffee
//= require i18n
//= require i18n/translations
//= require_tree ../templates/
//= require_tree ./admin
//= require_tree ./admin/theme
//= require_tree ./admin/subtheme

I18n.defaultLocale = "en";


Backbone.Marionette.Renderer.render = function(template, data) {
  if (!JST[template]) {
    throw "Template '" + template + "' not found!";
  }
  return JST[template](data);
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  return MyApp.start();
});
```

Now, we can prepare the admin part to start:

```
var AdminRouter, TempView;

// Create the application for admin part
MyApp.Admin = new Backbone.Marionette.Application();

// Define a router to handle the grid collection type change
AdminRouter = Backbone.Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    var _this = this;

    // Route quite generic to easily change the data in the grid
    this.route(/^admin\/(.*?)$/, "changeCollection");

    // Manage event to handle the navigation on client side
    MyApp.Admin.vent.on("admin:navigate", function(link) {
      _this.navigate(link, {
        trigger: true
      });
    });
  },

  // Trigger an event to change the collection if one exist for the URL
  changeCollection: function(collectionName) {
    MyApp.Admin.vent.trigger("grid:collection:change", collectionName);
  }
});

// Side menu that allows changing the collection in the data grid
SideMenuView = Backbone.Marionette.View.extend({
  el: ".side-menu",

  events: {
    "click a": "handleClick"
  },

  // Prevent the normal behavior on the link click
  handleClick: function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    MyApp.Admin.vent.trigger("admin:navigate", $(event.target).attr("href"));
  }
});

// Add the initializer to the main application to prepare the admin part (grid)
MyApp.addInitializer(function() {
  new SideMenuView();
  new AdminRouter();
  Backbone.history.start({
    pushState: true
  });
  MyApp.Admin.start();
});
```

Then we can define the datagrid part:

```
// This the grid layout module in the admin namespace
MyApp.Admin.module("GridLayout", function(GridLayout, Admin, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
  var ItemPageSelectorView, Layout, PagerView, QuickSearchView;

  // The quick search view handle the related fields to do the quick search
  QuickSearchView = Backbone.Marionette.View.extend({
    el: ".gridQuickSearch",

    events: {
      "keyup input": "search"
    },

    // Get the field content and trigger an event with it
    search: function(event) {
      var searchTerm;
      searchTerm = $(event.target).val().trim();
      $("input", this.$el).val(searchTerm);
      Admin.vent.trigger("grid:quickSearch:term", searchTerm);
    }
  });

  // The item page selecto handle the choice of how many rows should be displayed per page
  ItemPageSelectorView = Backbone.Marionette.View.extend({
    el: ".gridItemPageSelector",

    events: {
      "change select": "count"
    },

    // Get the number of items per page that should be displayed
    count: function(event) {
      var count;
      count = $(event.target).val();
      $("select", this.$el).val(count);
      Admin.vent.trigger("grid:itemPageSelector:count", count);
    }
  });

  // The pager view manage the view components to change the page shown in the data grid
  PagerView = Backbone.Marionette.View.extend({
    el: ".gridPager",

    events: {
      "click #next": "next",
      "click #previous": "previous",
      "click #first": "first",
      "click #last": "last",
      "click #page": "page"
    },

    //
    // The following functions triggers events to go to the right pages
    //
    first: function(event) {
      Admin.vent.trigger("grid:pager:first");
    },

    previous: function(event) {
      Admin.vent.trigger("grid:pager:previous");
    },

    page: function(event) {
      Admin.vent.trigger("grid:pager:page");
    },

    next: function(event) {
      Admin.vent.trigger("grid:pager:next");
    },

    last: function(event) {
      Admin.vent.trigger("grid:pager:last");
    }
  });

  // The grid layout with the regions to display the different part of the data grid
  Layout = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({
    template: "layouts/grid",

    regions: {
      gridTable: "#gridTable",
      gridQuickSearch: ".gridQuickSearch",
      gridItemPageSelector: ".gridItemPageSelector",
      gridPager: ".gridPager"
    }
  });

  // Once the layout is rendered, the different views are attached to the right regions
  Admin.vent.on("grid:layout:rendered", function() {
    var itemPageSelectorView, pagerView, quickSearchView;

    quickSearchView = new QuickSearchView();
    Admin.gridLayout.gridQuickSearch.attachView(quickSearchView);

    itemPageSelectorView = new ItemPageSelectorView();
    Admin.gridLayout.gridItemPageSelector.attachView(itemPageSelectorView);

    pagerView = new PagerView();
    Admin.gridLayout.gridPager.attachView(pagerView);
  });

  // Initializer to do at the application start
  GridLayout.addInitializer(function() {
    Admin.addRegions({
      content: ".content-box"
    });

    Admin.gridLayout = new Layout();

    // Trigger the rendered event when the grid layout is shown
    Admin.gridLayout.on("show", function() {
      Admin.vent.trigger("grid:layout:rendered");
    });

    // Manage the collection data change
    Admin.vent.on("grid:collection:change", function(collectionName) {
      // Close the previous view in the grid table region
      Admin.gridLayout.gridTable.close();

      // Trigger an event to fetch the collection
      Admin.vent.trigger("" + collectionName + ":collection:fetch");

      // Show the grid layout if not already done
      if (!this.shown) {
        this.shown = true;
        Admin.content.show(Admin.gridLayout);
      }
    });
  });

  return GridLayout;
});
```

We are done on the structural code. Now we can go to one of the controller. For example, the ThemeController:

```
MyApp.Admin.module("ThemeController", function(ThemeController, Admin, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
  // Define the model to use in the collection
  ThemeController.Theme = Backbone.Model.extend();

  // Define the collection with the related url on the server. The collection extends a paginated collection that has the methods to manage the quick search and the pagination
  ThemeController.Themes = Backbone.ExtendedCollection.paginatedCollection.extend({
    url: "/admin/themes",

    model: ThemeController.Theme,

    initialize: function() {
      var _this = this;

      //
      // The following functions handle the events for the quick search and pagination
      //

      Admin.vent.on("grid:quickSearch:term", function(term) {
        _this.quickSearch(term);
      });

      Admin.vent.on("grid:itemPageSelector:count", function(count) {
        _this.perPage(count);
      });

      Admin.vent.on("grid:pager:previous", function() {
        _this.previous();
      });

      Admin.vent.on("grid:pager:next", function() {
        _this.next();
      });

      Admin.vent.on("grid:pager:first", function() {
        _this.first();
      });

      return MyApp.Admin.vent.on("grid:collection:fetched", function() {
        Admin.gridLayout.gridTable.show(new Admin.ThemeView.Table({
          collection: _this
        }));
      });
    }
  });

  // At the application initilization, we need to be sure this controller can 
  // handle the event to fetch the data from the server
  Admin.addInitializer(function() {
    Admin.vent.on("themes:collection:fetch", function() {
      ThemeController.themes = new ThemeController.Themes();

      // Once the data are fetched from the server, trigger an event to display them
      ThemeController.themes.fetch({
        success: function() {
          Admin.vent.trigger("grid:collection:fetched");
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

And finally the views for the previous controller:

```
MyApp.Admin.module("ThemeView", function(ThemeView, Admin, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
  // The view to show one item in a row of the data grid
  ThemeView.Item = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: "tr",
    template: "admin/themes/theme",
    model: Admin.ThemeController.Theme
  });

  // The view to show the collection of item
  ThemeView.Table = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    template: "admin/themes/index",
    model: Admin.ThemeController.Theme,
    itemView: ThemeView.Item,
    collection: Admin.ThemeController.Themes,
    itemViewContainer: "#themes",

    // ! I was force to add this to have data in the original format that is used by my templates !
    serializeData: function() {
      return this.data;
    }
  });
});
```

**Remark:** The subtheme controller and view files contains exactly the same kind of codes. Only templates and kind of stuffs differ.

The grid layout in HAML compiled through Rails assets pipeline looks like:

```
.gridPager
  %button#first= "<<"
  %button#previous= "<"
  %button#next= ">"
  %button#last= ">>"

%span.gridItemPageSelector= "Item per page"
  %select
    %option= 5
    %option= 10
    %option{"value" => -1}= "All"

%span.gridQuickSearch= "Quick search:"
  %input#gridSearchTerm{"type" => "text"}

#gridTable

%span.gridItemPageSelector= "Item per page"
  %select
    %option= 5
    %option= 10
    %option{"value" => -1}= "All"

%span.gridQuickSearch= "Quick search:"
  %input#gridSearchTerm{"type" => "text"}

.gridPager
  %button#first= "<<"
  %button#previous= "<"
  %button#next= ">"
  %button#last= ">>"
```

As you can see, there is quite a lot of repetition. I wanted to have quick search and pagination on top and bottom of my grid. At the moment, the simplest way to do that is to duplicate the code. I will change that later when I will find how to do that.

The template for table that shows the themes:

```
%table.table.table-striped
  %thead
    %tr
      %th= "Id"
      %th= "Name"
  %tbody#themes
```

Quite simple and nothing special to say. At this time, the headers are hardcoded !

And finally, the item view template to show a theme:

```
%td= this.id
%td= this.name
```

This template is realy simple.

I am in a situation were that is pretty well working. For example, when I click on other links to change the collection shown, the quick search fields and kind stuff like that are not reinitialized. For that, I wanted to add a sort of state management to keep trace of the collection state and when come back to an already shown collection, I want to show it as it was previously.

I am sure that my solution is not perfect and could be refactored a lot. I also probably did a lot of "newbie" mistakes. So feel free to challenge my proposition. I try to learn and improve my solution and hope it will help someone to do something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Well I'm not a big expert but that's how I did it, using Marionette and Requirejs:

a) I created a generic Grid Layout wiew that is called by my approuter with some parameter like collection, cols config (I render the table head with a each cycle) and a row view:

```
showUsers: function(){

    require(['views/GridGen','collections/user_collection'], function(Grid, UserCollection){

        var Users = new UserCollection();

        App.grid = new Grid({collection: Users ,
                             rowView: 'rowUser',
                             cols_config: App.tables.users});

        App.page.show(App.grid);

    });
},
```

b) in my Grid Layout I render the various pieces waiting for the onShow event:

```
var Grid = Backbone.Marionette.Layout.extend({

regions: {
            top_controls: "#top_controls",
            table_view: "#table_view",
            pagination_controls: "#pagination_controls",
            bottom_controls: "#bottom_controls",
         },

onShow: function(){              
    this.renderTable(this.collection);
},

renderTable: function(collection){

    collection.fetch({success:function(){

          require(['views/'+self.options.rowView+'.js'],function(iView){

                   var vista = new View({collection: collection, itemView: iView, thead: self.options.cols_config});

                   App.grid.table_view.show(vista);

                   self.renderPagination(collection);

                   collection.pager();
               });
          }});
}
```

c) my generic Table View take the cols and the itemView to render as parameter like this:

```
var View = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({

initialize: function(){
        this.itemView = this.options.itemView;           
},
serializeData: function(){
        var data = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.prototype.serializeData.apply(this, arguments);
        data.thead = this.options.thead;
        return data;
},
appendHtml: function(collectionView, itemView, index){
        collectionView.$("tbody").append(itemView.el);
},
```

That's just a general idea, I don't think it's the best way to do it but I didn't find a better solution yet, hope to give you at least some hints :)

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will try something like that and see if it matches my needs.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend the [backgrid component](https://github.com/wyuenho/backgrid) which is extensible and reusable out of the box.

Only at version 0.2.6 - but good following and its pretty slick